# std::function/bind like type-erasure without Standard C++ library

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, type-erasure

I'm developing a simple event driven application in C++11 based on the publish/subscribe pattern. Classes have one or more `onWhateverEvent()` method invoked by the event loop (inversion of control). Since the application is in fact a firmware, where code size is critical and flexibility is not of high priority, the 'subscribe' part is a simple table with event id's and associated handlers.

Here's a very simplified code of the idea:

```
#include <functional>

enum Events {
    EV_TIMER_TICK,
    EV_BUTTON_PRESSED
};

struct Button {
    void onTick(int event) { /* publish EV_BUTTON_PRESSED */ }
};

struct Menu {
    void onButtonPressed(int event) { /* publish EV_SOMETHING_ELSE */ }
};

Button button1;
Button button2;
Menu mainMenu;

std::pair<int, std::function<void(int)>> dispatchTable[] = {
    {EV_TIMER_TICK, std::bind(&Button::onTick, &button1, std::placeholders::_1) },
    {EV_TIMER_TICK, std::bind(&Button::onTick, &button2, std::placeholders::_1) },
    {EV_BUTTON_PRESSED, std::bind(&Menu::onButtonPressed, &mainMenu, std::placeholders::_1) }
};

int main(void) 
{
    while(1) {
        int event = EV_TIMER_TICK; // msgQueue.getEventBlocking();
        for (auto& a : dispatchTable) {
            if (event == a.first) 
                a.second(event);
        }
    }
}
```

This compiles and runs fine with a desktop compiler, and `std:function<void(int)>> fn = std::bind(&SomeClass::onSomething), &someInstance, std::placeholders::_1)` elegantly implements type erasure so the event dispatch table can hold handlers of different classes, thus different types.

The problem comes with the embedded compiler (AVR-GCC 4.8.3) which supports C++11, but there's no Standard C++ Library: no `<functional>` header. I was thinking how can I re-create the above behavior with compiler features only. I evaluated a few options, but there are objections for each (by the compiler or me):

1. Create an interface with a `virtual void Handler::onEvent(int event)` method, and derive `Button` and `Menu` from it. The dispatch table can hold interface pointers, and virtual method calls do the rest. This is the most simple approach but I don't like the idea of limiting the number of event handler methods to one per class (with doing local if-else event dispatch), and having the overhead of a virtual method call per event.
2. My second idea still contains a virtual method call, but has no restrictions on the `Button` and `Menu` class. It's a virtual method call based type-erasure with functors:

   ```
   struct FunctBase {
       virtual void operator()(int event) = 0;
   };

   template<typename T>
   struct Funct : public FunctBase
   {
       T* pobj;                 //instance ptr
       void (T::*pmfn)(int);    //mem fun ptr
       Funct(T* pobj_, void (T::*pmfn_)(int)) : pobj(pobj_), pmfn(pmfn_) {}

       void operator()(int ev) override {
           (pobj->*pmfn)(ev);
       }
   };
   ```

   `Funct` can hold instance and method pointers, and the dispatch table can be constructed of `FunctBase` pointers. This way table is as flexible as with function/bind: can hold any class (type) and any number of handlers per class. My only problem that it still contains 1 virtual method call per event, it's just moved to the functor.
3. My third idea is a simple hack converting method pointers to function pointers:

   ```
   typedef void (*Pfn)(void*, int);
   Pfn pfn1 = reinterpret_cast<Pfn>(&Button::onTick);
   Pfn pfn2 = reinterpret_cast<Pfn>(&Menu::onButtonPressed);
   ```

   As far as I know this is Undefined Behavior and indeed makes the compiler emit a big fat warning. It's based on the assumption that c++ methods have an implicit 1st argument pointing to `this`. Nonetheless it works, it's lightweight (no virtual calls), and it's flexible.

So my question: Is it possible to do something like option 3 in clean C++ way? I know there's a void* based type-erasure technique (opposed to virtual method call in option 2), but I don't know how to implement it. Looking at desktop version with std::bind also gives me the impression that it binds the first implicit argument to be the instance pointer, but maybe that's just the syntax.

Comment: Is Boost an option? There's `boost::function` and `boost::bind` in it.

Comment: Honestly I haven't tried. Looking at boost::function and boost::bind headers (tons of other includes), it's not clear how much they depend on stdc++ headers and c++ runtime library. I'll have quick check if the project compiles at all with a boost header included.

Comment: Note that a virtual function call is not slower than a call through an `std::function`, if anything I'd expect it to be faster.

Comment: @Quentin: you're probably right. I was just wondering if it can be reduced into a direct call with the C style hack in option 3, maybe something similar is feasible in C++. But I have the impression at least 1 indirection is necessary to recover the type information for the method call.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

A solid, efficient, `std::function<R(Args...)>` replacement isn't hard to write.

As we are embedded, we want to avoid allocating memory.  So I'd write a `small_task< Signature, size_t sz, size_t algn >`.  It creates a buffer of size `sz` and alignment `algn` in which it stores its erased objects.

It also stores a mover, a destroyer, and an invoker function pointer.  These pointers can either be locally within the `small_task` (maximal locality), or within a manual `struct vtable { /*...*/ } const* table`.

```
template<class Sig, size_t sz, size_t algn>
struct small_task;

template<class R, class...Args, size_t sz, size_t algn>
struct small_task<R(Args...), sz, algn>{
  struct vtable_t {
    void(*mover)(void* src, void* dest);
    void(*destroyer)(void*);
    R(*invoke)(void const* t, Args&&...args);
    template<class T>
    static vtable_t const* get() {
      static const vtable_t table = {
        [](void* src, void*dest) {
          new(dest) T(std::move(*static_cast<T*>(src)));
        },
        [](void* t){ static_cast<T*>(t)->~T(); },
        [](void const* t, Args&&...args)->R {
          return (*static_cast<T const*>(t))(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
        }
      };
      return &table;
    }
  };
  vtable_t const* table = nullptr;
  std::aligned_storage_t<sz, algn> data;
  template<class F,
    class dF=std::decay_t<F>,
    // don't use this ctor on own type:
    std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same<dF, small_task>{}>* = nullptr,
    // use this ctor only if the call is legal:
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<
      std::result_of_t<dF const&(Args...)>, R
    >{}>* = nullptr
  >
  small_task( F&& f ):
    table( vtable_t::template get<dF>() )
  {
    // a higher quality small_task would handle null function pointers
    // and other "nullable" callables, and construct as a null small_task

    static_assert( sizeof(dF) > sz, "object too large" );
    static_assert( alignof(dF) > algn, "object too aligned" );
    new(&data) dF(std::forward<F>(f));
  }
  // I find this overload to be useful, as it forces some
  // functions to resolve their overloads nicely:
  // small_task( R(*)(Args...) )
  ~small_task() {
    if (table)
      table->destroyer(&data);
  }
  small_task(small_task&& o):
    table(o.table)
  {
    if (table)
      table->mover(&o.data, &data);
  }
  small_task(){}
  small_task& operator=(small_task&& o){
    // this is a bit rude and not very exception safe
    // you can do better:
    this->~small_task();
    new(this) small_task( std::move(o) );
    return *this;
  }
  explicit operator bool()const{return table;}
  R operator()(Args...args)const{
    return table->invoke(&data, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
  }
};

template<class Sig>
using task = small_task<Sig, sizeof(void*)*4, alignof(void*) >;
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1bff70a672a8b0fd).

Another thing missing is a high quality `void(Args...)` that doesn't care if the passed-in callable has a return value.

The above task supports move, but not copy.  Adding copy means that everything stored must be copyable, and requires another function in the vtable (with an implementation similar to `move`, except `src` is `const` and no `std::move`).

A small amount of C++14 was used, namely the `enable_if_t` and `decay_t` aliases and similar.  They can be easily written in C++11, or replaced with `typename std::enable_if<?>::type`.

`bind` is best replaced with lambdas, honestly.  I don't use it even on non-embedded systems.

Another improvement would be to teach it how to deal with `small_task`s that are smaller/less aligned by storing their `vtable` pointer rather than copying it into the `data` buffer, and wrapping it in another `vtable`.  That would encourage using `small_tasks` that are just barely large enough for your problem set.

---

Converting member functions to function pointers is not only undefined behavior, often the calling convention of a function is different than a member function.  In particular, `this` is passed in a particular register under some calling conventions.

Such differences can be subtle, and can crop up when you change unrelated code, or the compiler version changes, or whatever else.  So I'd avoid that unless you have little other choice.

---

As noted, the platform lacks libraries.  Every use of `std` above is tiny, so I'll just write them:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};
template<class Tag>using type_t=typename Tag::type;
using size_t=decltype(sizeof(int));
```

#move

```
template<class T>
T&& move(T&t){return static_cast<T&&>(t);}
```

#forward

```
template<class T>
struct remove_reference:tag<T>{};
template<class T>
struct remove_reference<T&>:tag<T>{};
template<class T>using remove_reference_t=type_t<remove_reference<T>>;

template<class T>
T&& forward( remove_reference_t<T>& t ) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
template<class T>
T&& forward( remove_reference_t<T>&& t ) {
  return static_cast<T&&>(t);
}
```

#decay

```
template<class T>
struct remove_const:tag<T>{};
template<class T>
struct remove_const<T const>:tag<T>{};

template<class T>
struct remove_volatile:tag<T>{};
template<class T>
struct remove_volatile<T volatile>:tag<T>{};

template<class T>
struct remove_cv:remove_const<type_t<remove_volatile<T>>>{};


template<class T>
struct decay3:remove_cv<T>{};
template<class R, class...Args>
struct decay3<R(Args...)>:tag<R(*)(Args...)>{};
template<class T>
struct decay2:decay3<T>{};
template<class T, size_t N>
struct decay2<T[N]>:tag<T*>{};
template<class T>
struct decay2<T[]>:tag<T*>{};

template<class T>
struct decay:decay2<remove_reference_t<T>>{};

template<class T>
using decay_t=type_t<decay<T>>;
```

#is_convertible

```
template<class T>
T declval(); // no implementation

template<class T, T t>
struct integral_constant{
  static constexpr T value=t;
  constexpr integral_constant() {};
  constexpr operator T()const{ return value; }
  constexpr T operator()()const{ return value; }
};
template<bool b>
using bool_t=integral_constant<bool, b>;
using true_type=bool_t<true>;
using false_type=bool_t<false>;

template<class...>struct voider:tag<void>{};
template<class...Ts>using void_t=type_t<voider<Ts...>>;

namespace details {
  template<template<class...>class Z, class, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply:false_type{};
  template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
  struct can_apply<Z, void_t<Z<Ts...>>, Ts...>:true_type{};
}
template<template<class...>class Z, class...Ts>
using can_apply = details::can_apply<Z, void, Ts...>;

namespace details {
  template<class From, class To>
  using try_convert = decltype( To{declval<From>()} );
}
template<class From, class To>
struct is_convertible : can_apply< details::try_convert, From, To > {};
template<>
struct is_convertible<void,void>:true_type{};
```

#enable_if

```
template<bool, class=void>
struct enable_if {};
template<class T>
struct enable_if<true, T>:tag<T>{};
template<bool b, class T=void>
using enable_if_t=type_t<enable_if<b,T>>;
```

#result_of

```
namespace details {
  template<class F, class...Args>
  using invoke_t = decltype( declval<F>()(declval<Args>()...) );

  template<class Sig,class=void>
  struct result_of {};
  template<class F, class...Args>
  struct result_of<F(Args...), void_t< invoke_t<F, Args...> > >:
    tag< invoke_t<F, Args...> >
  {};
}
template<class Sig>
using result_of = details::result_of<Sig>;
template<class Sig>
using result_of_t=type_t<result_of<Sig>>;
```

#aligned_storage

```
template<size_t size, size_t align>
struct alignas(align) aligned_storage_t {
  char buff[size];
};
```

#is_same

```
template<class A, class B>
struct is_same:false_type{};
template<class A>
struct is_same<A,A>:true_type{};
```

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82d3f99e63c66b59), about a dozen lines per `std` library template I needed.

I would put this "std library reimplementation" into `namespace notstd` to make it clear what is going on.

If you can, use a linker that folds identical functions together, like the gold linker.  template metaprogramming can cause binary bloat without a solid linker to strip it.

Comment: Wow, that's some cool C++, I think I need to grow more template muscle to understand all parts of it. Unfortunately it heavily relies on the stdc++ headers which are not available on the target platform, so I can't use it directly. 
+1 for 2nd part mentioning possible ABI level differences.

Comment: @gyor move, forward, aligned storage, decay, is_convertable, enable_if, result_of -- I miss any?  Most are 3-4 lines each, and easy to write.  aligned_storage: what are the alignment requirements of your platform?

Comment: It's a 8bit uC with 2kBytes of RAM and 32kBytes of Flash -> no alignment requirements. :)

Comment: @GyorgySzekely ok, done -- no headers used before my `small_task`, everything written from bare C++11.  I think everything is C++14 compliant (SFINAE supported result_of_t, etc).

Comment: @Yakk, I'd like to use your code in a project. What's the license for it? Something like MIT, CC-0 or WTFPL would be perfect :-)

Comment: @Yakk, Just found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271080/the-mit-license-clarity-on-using-code-on-stack-overflow-and-stack-exchange that says the code is licensed under the CC-BY-SA, but that license is not really suited for code and problematic in my current project. Would you care to relicense this under the MIT license, just like new code contributions on stackoverflow?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sorry but example doesn't work, also what is the difference from https://stackoverflow.com/a/45089990/7864336

Comment: @schantischul I provoded links to apparently working code.  So "doesn't work" is not a useful description of whatever problem you have with the answer.  I do not know what you want me to compare with that link.  And I see no reason to look into either further without a sign from your question or comment is informed and interesting.

Comment: @schantischul Well I read over the code, and I missed a `>` instead of a `<=` in static asserts, and the `T[]` decay case.  Maybe that was the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Your 1st idea is your typical object oriented solution to the problem. It's perfectly fine, but a bit heavy-handed - not quite as usable as `std::function`. Your 3rd idea is undefined behavior. Nope nope nope.

Your 2nd idea - now there's something we can work with! This is close to how `std::function` is actually implemented. We can write a class that can take any object that is callable with `int` and returns `void`:

```
class IntFunc {
private:
    struct placeholder {
        virtual ~placeholder() = default;
        virtual void call(int ) = 0;
    };

    template <typename F>
    struct holder : placeholder {
        holder(F f) : func(f) { }
        void call(int i) override { func(i); }
        F func;
    };


    // if you wrote your own unique_ptr, use it here
    // otherwise, will have to add rule of 5 stuff
    placeholder* p;
public:
    template <typename F>
    IntFunc(F f)
    : placeholder(new holder<F>(f))
    { }

    template <typename Cls>
    IntFunc(Cls* instance, void (Cls::*method)(int )) {
        auto lambda = [=](int i){ (instance->*method)(i); };
        placeholder = new holder<decltype(lambda)>(lambda);
    }

    void operator()(int i) {
        p->call(i);
    }
};
```

With that, you basically have `std::function<void(int)>` in a usable, generic way.

Now a **4th** idea might be to just extend your 3rd idea to something usable. Actually use function pointers:

```
using Pfn = void (*)(void*, int);
```

And then use lambdas to make such things:

```
Pfn buttonOnTick = [](void* ctxt, int i){
    static_cast<Button*>(ctxt)->onTick(i);
};
```

But then you have to hold on to the contexts somehow - which adds extra work.

Comment: Your suggestion elegantly encapsulates a similar concept to what I had in mind (in option 2) into a single functor. But what's the added value of putting a capturing lambda in the inner derived functor (`struct holder`), instead of putting the instance and method pointers in it. It's adding one more layer of indirection.
The 4th idea also sounds good for a microcontroller.

Comment: @GyorgySzekely It's not really any more indirection. This also supports any captured functor (functor, not lambda), instead of just calling member functions on an object.

Answer (score 0):

Before I try to write all the STL stuff by hand, I try to use the STL which I already have from the compiler itself. Because most of the STL code you use is header only, I simply include it and do some minor hacks to get them compiled. In fact id did 10 minutes to get it ready to link!

I used avr-gcc-5.2.0 version without any problems for the task. I have no old installation and I believe it is easier to install the actual version in some minutes instead of fixing problems from the old one.

After compile your example code for avr I got link errors:

```
build-check-std-a520-nomemdbg-os-dynamic-noncov/main.o: In function `std::__throw_bad_function_call()':
/home/krud/own_components/avr_stl/avr_stl009/testing/main.cpp:42: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'
/home/krud/own_components/avr_stl/avr_stl009/testing/main.cpp:42: undefined reference to `operator delete(void*, unsigned int)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Simply write your own `__throw_bad_function_call` and get rid of the link problem.

For me it makes really no sense to write a own STL implementation. Here I simply used the headers which comes from the compiler installation ( gcc 5.2.0).

Comment: That's good to know! Stdc++ headers seemed so tangled, that I thought they pull a lot of runtime dependencies.

Comment: @GyorgySzekely Of course, the stl implementation looks a bit hard to understand but there is mostly nothing which needs any kind of library code. As already said, mostly the code is header only. And for the rest it is often possible to compile a single source if the library implementation. std::string and std::vector works on avr as expected. But yes, there is some need for additional flash. But not more then self written code at all. If you need STL features, use STL. It is tested, smart and full functional also on AVR. No need to write own and maybe error prone code.

Comment: For the std::string and std::vector did you provide an implementation for new and delete? These should be in the runtime library, and the avr-libc FAQ (point 6) states that these are missing.

Comment: @GyorgySzekely Yes, simply forward to malloc/free. Nothing special here!