# catch std::function allocations at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, dynamic-memory-allocation, std-function

I want to only allow use of **std::function** in my code base if it does not do any allocations.

To this end I can write something like the function below and only use it to create my function instances:

```
template< typename Functor>
std::function<Functor> makeFunction( Functor f)
{
    return std::function<Functor>(std::allocator_arg, DummyAllocator(), f);
}
```

where DummyAllocator will assert or throw if it ever gets used at runtime.

Ideally though I would like to catch allocating use cases at compile time.

i.e.

```
template< typename Functor>
std::function<Functor> makeFunction( Functor f)
{
   static_assert( size needed for function to wrap f < space available in function, 
   "error - function will need to allocate memory");

   return std::function<Functor>(f);
 }
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: I don't think the Small Object Optimization is exposed in `std::function`, relying on it will result in nonportable code anyway. E.g. libc++ uses a buffer the size of 3 `void*`, which is different on 32 vs 64 bit x86 systems. libc++ uses `sizeof(__buf_)` to check if the SOO shall be applied, and I can't find any function where this info is exposed.

Comment: @dyp Well, the code itself is portable. It will compile and produce expected results on all platforms. If the idea is to only allow the usage of non-allocating std::function, no matter what (and I can see some reasonable scenarios calling for that) this is sensible approach. Catching allocations at compile time is not possible, since they are not happening at compile time.

Comment: @SergeyA Well you could catch them at compile time if the remaining code of the ctor was constexpr, but that isn't possible with SOO because it must use placement-new. My remark about portability was more of an attempt at explaining *why* it isn't exposed. Even `int x = 1 << 17;` is nonportable code, and I certainly agree that the nonportability in the OP is of the best kind (compiler error).

Comment: @dyp I think, it is concievable to create an implementation of std::function which would call two different functions based on the size of arguments - one which would have calls to allocate() in it, and another that would not. So providing an allocator which does not implement an allocate() will ensure no allocations and introduce a compile-time check.

Comment: @SergeyA While that is *possible*, it is not guaranteed that an implementation uses tag dispatching. libc++ certainly does not, it uses a plain `if(sizeof(_FF) <= sizeof(__buf_) && is_nothrow_copy_constructible<_Fp>::value)`. It looks like libstdc++ uses tag dispatching, but I'm not entirely sure (there is`_Local_storage`, and it's used for tag dispatching, but I would have to look at the whole code to determine whether or not it *always* uses tag dispatching).

Comment: @dyp, by no means I was implying that such implememtation exists. I was just saing, that it possible, and thus might be wished for in the future standard (I can definitely see a benefit of it), or simply implemented personally by using library implementation with modifications.

Comment: You could write a `std::function` act-alike that insists on only storing its data within itself, [like this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32079802/1774667).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The factory method you have is probably your best bet.

If not suitable, you may choose to implement an adaptor for `function`; implement the interface with the `std::function` as a member variable such that the adaptor enforces your constraints.

```
template <typename S>
class my_function {
  std::function<S> func_;
public:
  template <typename F>
  my_function(F&& f) :
  func_(std::allocator_arg, DummyAllocator(), std::forward<F>(f))
  {}
  // remaining functions required include operator()(...)
};
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd write a `std::function` replacement that does not allocate, as `std::function` does allocate memory if it needs to, here's one [candidate](https://github.com/janezz55/generic/blob/master/forwarder.hpp).

Answer (score 0):

Given `std::function` allocator support in your library, simply provide `std::function` with an allocator that doesn't work.

```
template< typename t >
struct non_allocator : std::allocator< t > {
    t * allocate( std::size_t n ) { throw std::bad_alloc{}; }
    void deallocate( t * ) {}

    non_allocator() = default;
    template< typename u >
    non_allocator( non_allocator< u > const & ) {}

    template< typename u >
    struct rebind { typedef non_allocator< u > other; };
};

template< typename t, typename u >
bool operator == ( non_allocator< t > const &, non_allocator< t > const & )
    { return true; }

template< typename t, typename u >
bool operator != ( non_allocator< t > const &, non_allocator< t > const & )
    { return false; }
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work in GCC because it does not even declare any `allocator_arg` constructors for `function`. Even in Clang, a compile-time error is impossible because it unfortunately uses a runtime `if` on a constant value to decide whether or not to use the allocator.